# How to remove nested clojure vector

Tags: clojure

I have

```
([[AA ww me bl qw 100] [AA ee rr aa aa 100] [AA qq rr aa aa 90]] [[CC ww me bl qw 100] [CC ee rr aa aa 67]])
```

and I need to remove the top nest so it becomes:

```
([AA ww me bl qw 100] [AA ee rr aa aa 100] [AA qq rr aa aa 90] [CC ww me bl qw 100] [CC ee rr aa aa 67])
```

Using flatten returns a list with just the inner elements which is not what I need. Thanks for helping..

Comment: use a sequence expression

Comment: ok, that sounds exciting but I have no idea what it is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `concat` to remove a single level of nesting. Since you have a sequence of sequences you need to use `apply`:

```
(apply concat
  ([[AA ww me bl qw 100] [AA ee rr aa aa 100] [AA qq rr aa aa 90]] [[CC ww me bl qw 100] [CC ee rr aa aa 67]]))
```